# Get SDL working with OSX Lion

Tags: macos, sdl, macports

SDL uses some functions that no longer work using the MacOSX10.7 SDK. I am not very familiar with MacPorts and I would like to know if there is a way to tell macports to build SDL using the 10.6 SDK instead.

If this is not possible, I can download the source and compile it myself, but again, I am not familiar with how to set the flags that I need. I would like a 32-bit build of SDL that uses the 10.6 SDK but runs on Lion.

Comment: Does the port libsdl-framework  not work?

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully built SDL framework for ppc, i386 and x86_64 using the following diff: http://r.research.att.com/sdl-1.2.14.diff
and the project in `SDL-1.2.14/Xcode/SDL/SDL.xcodeproj`. The diff uses 10.5 SDK so if you don't have that, you can simply change the 10.5 line to 10.6 and remove ppc.
If you don't want to build it, a binary is available at http://r.research.att.com/libs/SDL-1.2.14-fw-darwin9-bin3.tar.gz - it works on OS X 10.5 and higher (i.e., including Lion).

(I gave up to trying to fix the `configure` + `make` build which is broken for OS X since it has a lot of stuff hard-coded that is many years out of date, because I needed it quickly...)